# ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous' when applying Random Forrest

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

I have a dataset `df_train` and some labels for it `df_train_labels`.

```
print(df_train.shape)
print(df_train_labels.shape)
```

outputs:

```
(1460, 6)
(1460,)
```

and

```
print(df_train[0:4])
print(df_train_labels[0:4])
```

outputs

```
   OverallQual  GrLivArea  GarageCars  TotalBsmtSF  FullBath  YearBuilt
0            1   0.000000           1            1         1          1
1            1   0.000000           0            1         0          1
2            0   0.693147           0            2         0          2
3            0   1.098612           1            3         1          3
0    2.505338
1    2.493950
2    2.510994
3    2.472277
Name: SalePrice, dtype: float64
```

I am trying to fit a model on this data:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10)
clf = clf.fit(df_train, df_train_labels)
```

However, the last line fails with this error:

```
raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % y_type)
ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'
```

I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45645716/unknown-label-type-continuous) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45645043/unknown-label-type-continuous) but I didn't see any information relevant to my problem.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: The answer to your question is in both of the posts you linked here. `df_train_labels` contains real numbers but you are using a ***classifier*** which expects discrete numbers (`labels`). Perhaps, you want `RandomForestRegressor` instead of `RandomForestClassifier`.

Answer (score 8):

`RandomForestClassifier` doesn't seem to work with floats, so I used `RandomForestRegressor` instead.

Comment: "doesn't seem to work" doesn't quite cover the fact it is simply not designed for it! You are doing a regression not a classification, so were using the wrong thing.

Comment: Please first understand the problem you are tackling here. You are trying to predict continuous values which is a regression task.

Answer (score 0):

If your solution demands **classification** instead of **regression** then I will suggest you use non-continuous label list like [0,1,2,3] and create a one-to-one mapping with the original label list.